# running an xap (silverlight app) in VS 2005

Tags: silverlight, xap

I've written a small `silverlight` app in vs 2008.  Now I'd like to plug that app into a site that was developed using vs.net 2005. what are the steps needed to do this.  This is what I've done so far.

**In web.config**

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>

<controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls" assembly="System.Web.Silverlight, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        </controls>
```

**In the asp page.**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
Namespace="System.Web.UI" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls" Assembly="System.Web.Silverlight, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        Silverlight Test
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" />
        <div style="height: 100%;">
            <asp:Silverlight ID="silverlightControl" runat="server" Source="~/TypingTestV2.xap"
                MinimumVersion="2.0.31005.0" Width="100%" Height="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When i run the app, i get an error in IE

> Webpage error details : 
>   User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; OfficeLiveConnector.1.4; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)
>   Timestamp: Fri, 7 Aug 2009 13:12:30 UTC
>   Message: ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
>   Line: 38
>   Char: 34
>   Code: 0
>   URI: htt://localhost:4063/Silverlight.aspx
>
> Message: 'Sys' is undefined
>   Line: 48
>   Char: 1
>   Code: 0
>   URI: htt://localhost:4063/Silverlight.aspx
>
> Message: 'Sys' is undefined
>   Line: 57
>   Char: 1
>   Code: 0
>   URI: htt://localhost:4063/Silverlight.aspx
>
> Message: 'Sys' is undefined
>   Line: 67
>   Char: 1
>   Code: 0
>   URI: htt://localhost:4063/Silverlight.aspx

and in Firefox :

> ASP.NET Ajax client-side framework failed to load.
>   [Break on this error] if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw n...ient-side framework failed to load.');\r\n

So i'm not sure what the problem is. although it says `AJAX`, I'm not sure what the next step would be

(the htt above was http, but the site won't allow me to do more than one hyperlink in the post, so i changed it to htt)
hope someone is willing to help.
Shannon

Answer (score 3):

Sliverlight 3 has dropped the asp silverlight server control, hence you would be better off duplicating the content of the test .htm page that VS 2008 creates.  Use the `<object>` tag directly in your ASP.NET 2.0 app.